# Unity Input System On-Screen Button doesn't work with touchscreen 2019.3.2f1

Tags: unity, gui, input

I am trying to make my player jump whenever the space button is pressed (if a keyboard is present), and I'm adding a on-screen button for players on mobile. The on-screen button works fine in the editor but when I try the game in a device the on-screen button doesn't work.

Here's how things are set up:

- Change the `Active Input Handling` to `Input System Package (New)` on
  the player settings.
- Create the `Jump` action for the `Player` action map.
- Bind `<Keyboard>/space` to my `Jump` action.
- Add a `PlayerInput` component to my player object, pass my actions
  file to it, and set up the events to call for each action.
- Change the `StandaloneInputModule` to an `InputSystemUIInputModule` in my
  event system object.
- In my canvas I add an image and add `OnScreenButton` component to it (I
  do NOT add a `Button` component).
- Set the control path to `<Keyboard>/space`.

When I try the game on the device the rest of the UI buttons work fine except the on-screen button. On the editor though (using mouse input), the on-screen button works fine.
This is my first time using the Input System, I had actually found it somewhat nice to work with, however this does seem really strange. It is either a really strange bug (unlikely), or I messed up some setting (the setup process feels really convoluted actually).